# Using the Mongodb $in filter in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to build a search function for a REST API using mongodb and C#.

I am trying to use the $in mongodb filter in a query. I know that hard coding the filter string `{\"name\":{$in:[/^First/]}}` find the record as I wish to, however I cannot get the same functionality when using `Filter.In`.

In my mongo repo I have a GetAsync that takes in the `name` and does the following:

```
return await Context
                .Collection<TChronosDocument>()
                .Find(
                    //"{\"name\":{$in:[/^First/]}}")
                   Builders<TChronosDocument>.Filter.In(x => name, ToRegex(name)))
                .Sort(SortDefinition)
                .Page(offset, limit)
                .ToListAsync()
                .ToAggregate(Mapper);
```

The `ToRegex` function merely converts a string like `First` into a string[] like `[/^First/]` for use by the filter.

The problem here is that this returns an empty array for the results instead of correctly matching to the entry with `name : "First Agency"`.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about achieving the $in functionality in C#, or if I am just doing something else wrong here.

(PS: I have tried using `Find(Builders<TChronosDocument>.Filter.In(name, ToRegex(name)))` with no luck either).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Builders<TChronosDocument>.Filter.In(x => name, ToRegex(name)))
```

with

```
Builders<TChronosDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => name, ToRegex(name))
```